# DynamoDB indexing on payload

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, aws-iot, amazon-dynamodb-streams

My DynamboDB row item looks like this: (it is given to me)

```
{
     "id":"123456",
     "date_time":"01062016 143212",
     "payload":{
         "type":"A",
         "value":"temp value",
     }
}
```

I added indexes on id + date_time.
how can you add index on **payload.type**?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB doesn't support indices on nested fields inside `Map`.

See official documentation [Improving Data Access with Secondary Indexes in DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html).

> The key schema for the index. Every attribute in the index key schema must be a top-level attribute of type String, Number, or Binary. Other data types, including documents and sets, are not allowed.